# Vuetify: How to listen close event of a dialog?

Tags: vuetify.js

I think `<v-dialog @close="close">` does not work.

How to listen close event of a dialog?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The vuetify docs aren't showing any `close` event for dialog maybe you could double check or clarify the vuetify version (if that's the case)

A workaround without event could be using watch:

```
<script>
export default {
 data(){
  show:false
 },
 watch:{
  show:function(newValue, old){
   if(!newValue){
    // Closing
   }
  }
 }
}
</script>
```

And you use the dialog with v-model: `<v-dialog v-model="show">`

Whenever `show` equals `true` the dialog will show, and using the watcher you will know when `show` is being set to `false` and closing the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement your own close event. I mean, at your close or save button click you emit 'close'.

```
 <template>
   <v-dialog v-model="dialog">
     <v-card>
       ...
       <v-card-actions>
          <v-spacer></v-spacer>
          <v-btn text @click="close"> Close </v-btn>
          <v-btn text @click="close"> Save </v-btn>
       </v-card-actions>
     </v-card>
  </v-dialog>
</template>    
<script>
export default {
  props: ["dialog"],
  methods: {
    close() {
      this.$emit("close");
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For this you could actually use @input event. Since my activator button is outside my component, I used the "activated" prop to trigger the dialog, and since we shouldn't mutate props from inside the component, I emit the `update:activated` event when the dialog is closed.

```
<template>
    <v-dialog v-model="dialog" @input="close">
    </v-dialog>
</template>    

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                dialog: false
            };
        },
        props: {
            activated: {
                type: Boolean
            }
        },
        watch: {
            activated: {
                immediate: true,
                handler(newValue) {
                    if (newValue) {
                        this.dialog = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        methods: {
            close() {
                this.$emit('update:activated', false);
            }
        }
    };
</script>
```